# How do I access a git repo on a windows share?

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, share, git-remote

I want to be able to sync a work repo from my Windows 7 desktop to my Windows 7 laptop without pushing my commits to our main server. How do I do this? I can't figure out how to set up a remote path so that git can understand where it is. I generally use Git Bash for dealing with git, not the windows commandline, so the issue here is likely that I can't figure out how to write a path in Git Bash which will reference a windows share.

So, say I have a repo at (windows share path):

```
\\\\MyWorkPCName\dev\myrepo\
```

And in the command line, I can access the directories and files (albeit using pushd since cmd is stupid), how do I convert this in to a valid git remote?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While Git doesn't recognize backslashes, Windows *does* recognize forward slashes:

```
git remote add desktop //MyWorkPCName/dev/myrepo
```

Git Bash also lets you access windows drives using UNIX-style paths, e.g. `C:\Users\bug\repo` becomes `/c/Users/bug/repo`.

Comment: Unfortunately this was the very first thing I tried. I get "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Also, I can't cd to a share directory from within git bash. Maybe part of the problem?

Comment: Try running that line from a `cmd` prompt (unless you installed msysgit with the "Git Bash only" option) and/or using `file://\\MyWorkPC\etc` (with single quotes if using bash).

Comment: Your original answer was correct. Flaky network may be an explanation for why it wasn't working for me originally.

Comment: The answer is correct. Note that "Not a git repository" may also indicate you're not in a git repository locally (duh!)