# How to setup a remote for git that it's in my c disk (win vista)?

Tags: git, git-remote

I would like to know how to create a remote into a windows folder because all the tuts shows me how to make a remote into a remote server and not a folder. http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/

Comment: http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple/

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://blog.mrdustpan.com/2011/09/git-dropbox-crazy-delicious.html) shows an example of a remote on the C drive:

```
git remote add origin c:/dropbox/repos/theAwesome
```

Although the following syntax should work too:

```
git remote add origin /C/dropbox/repos/theAwesome
```

Comment: With both commands I get the same error: fatal: "'c:/folder' does not appear to be a git repository; fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly; ". Is correct to use "/" instead of "\" in windows?

Comment: @Totty Yes, you can use '`/`' on Windows, since git is using msys (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/difference-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git?rq=1). Did you create a git repo in `/c/folder` first? As in "`cd c:\folder`", and "`git init --bare`"

Comment: @Totty in the case, it could be a case issue. Because the paths are correct, as this example illustrates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9104446/6309. Another option: try to *clone* your bare repo, and check what `git remote -v show` returns in your cloned repo..