# Setting up Git Locally for use with Intellij Idea 12

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've been at this all night but can't seem to get anything working.

Here's what I want to do:

I have a project in IntelliJ Idea 12 that I want to use with Git.  I want to use git locally for my personal use.

I have installed git and set it as my VCS in IntelliJ.  However, I can't actually push anything because Intellij says that there is no remote set.  In git bash, I set up a 'remote' folder elsewhere and called the folder 'Project.git'.

Then I navigate back to my intelliJ project and used the command:

```
git remote add origin C:\Users\Me\RemoteFolder.git
```

No errors.

Then I push and get the following error:

```
fatal: 'C:UsersMeRemoteFolder.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?  Or just give me a simple guide for setting up Git locally with Intellij? I have tried their documentation and about 100 google searches and cannot ever seem to find the answers to my questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a **[bare repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)** (`git init --bare C:\Users\Me\RemoteFolder.git`) in order to push to it.

Second, you need to declare that remote taking into account the fact that backslash (`\`) are not well supported. [This should work better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104446/6309):

```
git remote add /C/Users/Me/RemoteFolder.git
# or even
git remote add C:/Users/Me/RemoteFolder.git
```