# Android Studio git checkout

Tags: android, android-studio

While trying new android ide i meet a problem when i can't import progect from local server git repository (\server\git-repo\android\progect). In Eclipse EGit plugin everything works fine.

```
Clone Failed 
fatal: repository '\\server\git-repo\android\progect\' does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104266/how-do-i-access-a-git-repo-on-a-windows-share/9104446#9104446)
Problem is that Android Studio(i.e. IntelliJ IDEA) uses git and git doesn't work with back slashes.

Correct path will be `//server/git-repo/android/progect/`

This is seems to be not a problem for git users, but can cause some problems for developers which use Eclipse+EGit